# React.js + Flux, immediate response during history back/forward

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, reactjs, flux

In Instagram (web), when you click back/forward arrows - I've noticed that the content isn't loaded from the server and it immediately show up. After reading the docs on react.js + flux, I had this understanding:

`Action -> Dispatcher -> Stores ...` where the `stores`would listen for changes and load new data from server in an array e.g: `{"data": post_id: 10}`

I really want to achieve this, since right now I'm loading content using ajax + push state 
(`window.onpopstate =  history.onpushstate = function() {  ...... }`).        
And the problem with using this, is that all content loaded on scroll (e.g: posts) are lost during navigation. And when you return back, you start from beginning, so you have to scroll to the point you stopped at last time. I noticed this problem on Facebook website, yet not in Instagram...

So my questions are:

- Does the immediate response comes from stores? If so in what format and how?
- Is react.js the only way to achieve this, maybe using *backbone* or *angular*?
- Why Facebook website doesn't  use this and Instagram does?

Please give me some examples (code) or links, since I'm new to this..Thanks

Comment: 1.  The content on the back/forward arrows is probably being loaded and cached.

Comment: 2.  Of course not.

Comment: 3.  The short answer is that facebook is not instagram, and they made different design decisions.

Comment: Robert Harvey - After experimenting I think that Instagram creates objects for each page, hides them and shows during navigation, because this feature disappears after page reload.. What do you think?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to implement this behavior would be to cache the ajax responses somewhere.

That way you wouldn't have to change any of the react/flux code (or any framework at all).
When you click the back button, the API would return a cached result instead of making a new request, and the data would be available instantly.

Here is a naïve implementation with the [memoize() function](https://lodash.com/docs#memoize) from lodash :

```
var fetchPage = function(id) {};
var fetchPageCached = _.memoize(fetchPage);
```

That way, if you call `fetchPageCached()` twice, it will return the same result but issuing only one ajax request.

That said, I don't know why facebook doesn't cache previous pages...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this feature is called time travelling and it comes from flux or redux. I use redux, go check it out: http://redux.js.org